# Can AS/400 Database Tables Be Hidden?

Tags: database, ibm-midrange, dbvisualizer

I was trying to delete a record from a table in AS/400 database. I got an error message saying that there is a referential integrity to another table XYZ in the same Schema ABC.

To my wonder, that table was not in the list of the tables shown by my DbVisualizer database client.

Then I decided to do a select on that table (ABC.XYZ) - but I got the records back. Thinking that it might be a client problem, I used another Client (AS/400 Operations Navigator) - I had the same results: table not on the list, but got the results back when I did a SELECT * FROM ABC.XYZ

My questions is, can the AS/400 tables be hidden in such a manner?

(Please note that the table was not even in the views/system table/Alias/Materialized Query Table)

Comment: First, it might not be a 'table'. If it's a view, it won't show in a list of tables. Also, some native files can be "invisible" to SQL-based clients, e.g., a multi-format logical file. However, most such files cannot be queried by SQL, so any SELECT will fail. We would need to see at least the file description from the system to determine why the file isn't seen yet can be SELECTed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables can be "hidden" via authorities on the object. Do you have *ALLOBJ authority?

Comment: Authority would cause SELECT to fail.